# How to consume TokenAuthentication based user authentication built in DRF in Django web application

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created a WebAPI for user authentication using Token Authentication built on Django Rest Framework. with the help of Postman I am able to determine that my user is being created, authenticated and logged out successfully.

I have created a Django web application and have successfully consumed the WebAPI endpoints which do not require authentication in my HTML files.

Now I wish to create user Login/Logout functionality and since I am new to the subject, I don't know how to do this.

Please help? a link to a tutorial would be appreciated

Regards,

Arun

Answer (score -1):

That not token authentication but may be help you

[clik](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJRGQoqpRwddrFlVEQV16D1jdol40ETyx)